# VFS Gold Service UK Visa from USA

Tags: b1-b2-visas, vfs-global, biometric-passports

How long is processing time for Gold Service VFS Visa?  How long to get passport back to Chicago office to pick up?

Comment: Have you checked the VFS website, or asked their help team?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold for now.